# How to read mathematical "union" in German

Tags: mathematics

How is the set "A union B" read in German? Is it "Die Vereinigung von A und B" or "A vereinigt mit B"?

(Also, is there some place that describes how mathematical expressions are read in German?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both is correct.
The "Vereinigungsmenge" is read as:

- *A vereinigt mit B* or
- *Die Vereinigung(or Vereinigungsmenge) von A und B*

Consequently, the "Schnittmenge" is read as:

- *A geschnitten mit B* or
- *Die Schnittmenge von A und B*

Wikipedia is indeed a great place to start, but I also suggest – in case you're interested in maths – to watch lectures on Youtube. I can really recommend, for example, the videos of [Christian Spannagel](http://www.youtube.com/user/pharithmetik/videos?flow=grid&view=1).

Comment: When reading a formula one might also omit the „mit“ and say only „A vereinigt B“.

Comment: It's not just that one 'might' do it, it's what everyone normally does.Similarly "A geschnitten B". The other options are too long for daily use.

Answer (score -1):

Union ist Vereinigung. Wikipedia ist oft hilfreich, wenn es um Fachbegriffe geht, die ein normales Wörterbuch nicht aufführt. In diesem Fall https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menge_%28Mathematik%29

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I'm interested in how "A union B" is **read out loud** in German. I don't think you've answered that question.

Comment: Die Vereinigung von A und B.

Comment: @Robert: Du solltest die Antwort selbst korrigieren, nicht die Antwort im Kommentar nachschieben.